# How to add hundreds of shapes on page without slowing page load

Tags: javascript, html, svg, pageload

I am trying to add hundreds of little "squares"/shapes on a page using JS. However, whether using SVG or divs, the page load is very slow. Is there a more efficient way to create multiple shapes on a page without slowing down the page load?

Here is an example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yrvLub3/), which has both svg and div examples

Here is the JS:

```
var num = 700
for (i=0; i < num; i++){
    let el = '<div class="els"></div>';
  let elSVG = '<svg class="els"></svg>';
  let container = document.getElementById("test");
  
 container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + elSVG
}
```

Comment: How about `container.append(elSVG)` where `elSVG` is an actual element?

Comment: sounds like canvas would be a better bet than SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of concatenating HTML text to the `innerHTML` each time, `append` an `<svg>` element. Also, you should only query for `#test` (aka `container`) once; outside of your loop.

```js
const
  container = document.getElementById('test'),
  num = 700;

const createSvg = () => {
  const svg = document.createElement('SVG');
  svg.classList.add('els');
  return svg;
};

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  container.append(createSvg());
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #111
}

.els {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

**Update:** As Danny mentioned, you could append all the SVG elements to a `DocumentFragment` and then append said fragment to the container afterwards.

```js
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  fragment.append(createSvg());
}
container.append(fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always slow page load, it can **not** be done *without slowing down*.

But you can be smart in creating content.

- innerHTML and append will trigger Browser reflow/repaint for every insertion
- Use a DocumentFragment to built all HTML **in memory**, then inject the DocumentFragment once.

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment
- You might also want to look into `<template>`,
  a **cloned** template parses the HTML only **once**

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

```html
<style>
  body {
    background-color: black
  }
  .els {
    height: 2px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div id="$Container">
</div>
<script>
  console.time();
  let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  let num = 4 * 700;
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.classList.add("els");
    el.appendChild(document.createElement("svg"))
      .classList.add("els");
    fragment.append(el);
  }
  $Container.append(fragment);
  console.timeEnd();
</script>
```